# What Does Microsoft Office Have on WP8 that it doesn't on 7.5?

Tags: 8.0, 7.5, office-hub

I'm deciding whether to upgrade now to a Windows Phone 8, and if there are major improvements to the implementation of Microsoft Office (including Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote), then that will easily justify my decision.

What are the improvements to Office included in WP8 that 7.5 doesn't have?

Comment: The only I'm aware is the standalone app for OneNote. You can go back and forward in sections and pages there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mostly aesthetic and workflow streamlining changes.

## Office Hub

[image: Windows Phone 7.5 Office Hub]
<sub>(source: [futurecdn.net](http://cdn0.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net/Review%20images/TechRadar/Mobile%20phones/Windows%20Phone%207/Windows%20Phone%207.5%20Mango/office%20hub%20colour%20coded-420-100.jpg))</sub>

[image: Windows Phone 8 Office Hub]

The Office logos have been updated, and the tabs have been renamed. Recent documents are shown in a list rather than tiles. OneNote is a separate app and is not in the Office Hub. The recent documents list is synchronized with Office 2013 and Office Online.

In the individual apps, the top bar is a solid color (e.g., blue for Word) rather than white/transparent.

## Word

Word is basically identical in WP7.5 and WP8.

## Excel

[image: WP7.5 Excel]
[image: WP8 Excel]

The column and row headings are prettier. The Outline button has been changed to Sheets. You can sort numbers with the new Sort button. Comment has been moved from the action bar to the overflow, and Sort has moved from the overflow to the action bar.

## PowerPoint

[image: WP7.5 PowerPoint]
[image: WP8 PowerPoint]

Selecting text to edit is more direct. In WP8, you directly tap on the text, whereas in WP7.5, you tap the slide and press the Next button to go through the different text boxes. Notes are below the slide, no longer accessed through the Notes button. Outline [image: Outline] has been changed to Slides [image: Slides].

## OneNote

[image: WP7.5 OneNote]
[image: WP8 OneNote]

You can use Speech or Cortana to add notes. Navigation is different because OneNote isn't part of the Office Hub.

Answer (score 1):

The following Urls tell about the improvements:

Part 1: http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/11/19/windows-phone-8-office-improvements-part-one/

Part 2: http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/11/20/windows-phone-8-office-improvements-part-two/

Comment: It might be a good idea if you could summarise the improvements. This will avoid link rot and provide a nice overview.